# How do I slightly shrink an image with CSS in a surgical manner, for use with Amazon direct publishing?

Tags: css

Changing image sizes with CSS has been done a few times - I read a few questions and answers on the subject, trying hard not to duplicate - but I've got a bit of a twist on the standard problem. Instead of trying to get my CSS interpreted by IE or Chrome or whatever, I'm formatting a book for publication on Amazon. For whatever godforsaken reason, epubs have a CSS backend.

Now, my book has ~fancy~ dividers for scene breaks, which is uploaded as a .png. The formatting then grabs the image, and applies the right stylesheet CSS.

I'm a hair too large for Amazon, and they're yelling at me over margins. I have no idea what it is in pixels, because this is for a paperback book. I need to shrink my image by about 5%. The picture is pulled up like this

```
<p class="block_16"><img src="images/Book%20Line%20Breaks%20Red.png" alt="Image" class="calibre6"/></p>
```

And the relevant classes:

```
.calibre6 {
display: block;
height: auto;
width: auto
}

.block_16 {
display: block;
text-align: justify;
text-indent: 28.8pt;
margin: 0;
padding: 0
}
```

Naturally, what the epub CSS thinks of as "Auto", and what Amazon KDP thinks of as "Auto" don't match. I suspect the following snippet will work, but it's ~30 minutes of uploading files and data crunching for Amazon to confirm:

```
width: 95%;
height: auto;
```

Am I on the right track, or going off horribly into the weeds?

Thank you!

Comment: "they're yelling at me over margins" What's the wording of their complaint? (What's the error?)

Comment: If you just "need to shrink my image by about 5%", you could simply add `transform: scale(0.95)` to your `calibre6` class style and leave `width` and `height` as `auto`.

Comment: I don't know why it's so tricky to upload to KDP, I've uploaded several books for digital and paperback, and the templates they give should keep you from going astray. What's the exact error Amazon gives?

Comment: The exact error is "This image is outside the margins", because my scene break picture is too large. Transform should work, let me try it

Comment: Welp, Scale works great in the testing window, but Amazon KDP doesn't recogize it. It was overflowing even at 1%. Going to try a few more things

Comment: Solution is dissatisfying: I had to manually play with pixel sizes until Amazon accepted it. 72x 384 ended up being the winning numbers.